# How to Add a Geocoding Service as a Form of Plugin (For Leaflet)

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, leaflet, geocode

I am specifically using Leaflet Routing Machine plugin and I have been trying to add a geocoding service to the plugin but I have been facing some difficulties. I tried Bing, Google and Nominatim but I'm unable to load any of the geocoding service successfully.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me on this? I hope to add the geocoding service for free. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this tutorial for information on adding a geocoder to Leaflet Routing Machine: http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/geocoders/

For most of the geocoders, alternatives are fetched when hitting enter in the input field. The Mapbox geocoder has autocomplete, as mentioned in the tutorial. You can also add autocomplete yourself, depending on which service you use (note that for example Nominatim explicitly forbids using their public servers for autocomplete).